# How to handle confirmation with RACCommand

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I've just started using `ReactiveCocoa` inside my project. I am trying to figure out how to handle confirmation requests while using a `UIAlertView`.

I just can't seem to wrap my head around this.

1. Enable Button with validation
2. Show `UIAlertView` and check which button index is selected
3. If Yes, go ahead and fetch data from the server, if not do nothing.

How can I get the UIAlertView to appear first before executing begins?

```
class MyViewModel: NSObject {
    dynamic var myText = ""

    var executeTransaction: RACCommand!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        let validSignal = RACObserve(self, "myText").mapAs {
            (text: NSString) -> NSNumber in
            return text.length >= 10
        }.distinctUntilChanged()

        self.executeTransaction = RACCommand(enabled: validSignal, signalBlock: {
        (any: AnyObject!) -> RACSignal! in
            return self.executingTransactionSignal()
        })
    }

    func executingTransactionSignal() -> RACSignal! {
        return RACSignal.createSignal {
            subscriber in
            subscriber.sendNext("testing")
            subscriber.sendCompleted()
            return nil
        }
    }
}


class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.inputField.rac_textSignal() ~> RAC(self.viewModel, "myText")

        self.verifyButton.rac_command = self.viewModel.executeTransaction

        let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Continue", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Change", otherButtonTitles: "Yes")

        let alertSignal = return alert.rac_buttonClickedSignal().map({ (buttonIndex) -> AnyObject! in
            let index = buttonIndex as Int
            return index == 1
        })

        // trying see how to show, and subscribe to self.viewModels.executeTransaction.executionSignals 
    }
}
```

---

Update...

What I ended up doing was creating a method in my view model that takes in a closure, and returns the RACCommand. I am not really sure If this is the most elegant way though.

Comment: I haven't learned Swift yet, so I can't read your code too easily but if you explain what you want in RAC terms a bit better I can help you.

Comment: I am just trying to get confirmation with a UIAlertView before executing the request. I am using the mvvm pattern. Getting the confirmation I dont think that should live in the view model but should be owned by the view controller.

Comment: Ok so then just hook up the button to an UIAlertView and then hook the ok button on the UIAlertView to another signal that executes the request?